# BGAppRefreshTaskRequest is not being called from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background, fetch

I want to run a background fetch in my iOS app. But iOS is not calling my registered Handler. I tried some similar answers on other posts but nothing helps.

"Permitted background task scheduler identifiers" is set in `info.plist` and
Background Mode "Background fetch" is enabled

[image: Capability]

my app should send a notification, if the background fetch is running .... but nothing happens for hours

calling the background fetch with `e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"myUniqueIdentifier"]` is doing nothing or results in an error

I'm testing on a real device

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks

@main
struct BackgroundTestApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    let identifier = "myUniqueIdentifier"
    
    init() {
        registerAppRefreshTask()
        registerNotifications()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                    if phase == .active {
                        
                    }
                    if phase == .background {
                        print("App: Enter Background.")
                        scheduleAppRefresh()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

```
private func registerNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("Notifications: Authorized.")
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

```
    private func registerAppRefreshTask() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: identifier,
                                        using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        print("App: BackgroundTask registered.")
    }
```

```
func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
    
    scheduleAppRefresh()
    
    let refreshQueue = OperationQueue()
    refreshQueue.qualityOfService = .background
    refreshQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    
    let refreshOperation = BlockOperation {
        
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            NotificationManager.shared.send("App", "Oh i'm awake")
        }
    }
    
    refreshOperation.completionBlock = { task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)}
    
    task.expirationHandler = {
        refreshQueue.cancelAllOperations()
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
    }
}
```

```
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: identifier)
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
        
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
            print("App: Scheduled Background Task.")
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh \(error).")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “... or results in an error”. What is the error?

Comment: "2021-02-02 20:38:48.303748+0100 BackgroundTest[3534:1442524] Starting simulated task: <decode: missing data>"

Comment: That’s not an error. That’s what it says when the simulated task starts. When you resume execution in lldb, it should run. Don’t worry about the “missing data” portion.

Comment: I don't know why but its working now. Thanks for your help.